# AMQPCPP Consumer And publisher don't create exchange and queues

Tags: linux, c++11, rabbitmq, amqp

Message Not Consumed:When you run my_publish to publish a message and then run my_consume to consume messages, the messages are not consumed as expected.
Steps Taken to resolve the issue & Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

- Message Routing: The primary purpose of message brokers like RabbitMQ is to route messages from publishers to consumers. If messages are not reaching consumers, it could be due to misconfigured exchanges or bindings. I have verified them but i will be providing the codes below in case i missed something.
- Permissions: User has admin privileges.
- Network and Firewall: I've confirmed that your RabbitMQ server is reachable.
- I've checked the RabbitMQ server's status, installed and configured ufw to allow incoming connections on port 5672, and verified that you can ping the RabbitMQ server successfully.
- Host Name Resolution: Verify that the hostname or IP address in your connection string is correct and that hostname resolution is working.
- RabbitMQ Configuration: Double-check the RabbitMQ server's configuration, including exchanges, queues, and permissions.
- RabbitMQ Management Interface: Access the RabbitMQ Management Interface to inspect the server's status, connections, exchanges, queues, and bindings. Regardless of my multiple aattemps no exchanges or queues were created/added.
- Additional Logging: I added a print statement after the publish message which means the execution of my_publish goes very well.
- RabbitMQ Server Version Compatibility: Ensure that your RabbitMQ server version is compatible with the amqpcpp library version used in your C++ programs.
  'Status of node rabbit@thimonnier-desktop ...
  Runtime

OS PID: 56992
OS: Linux
Uptime (seconds): 15076
RabbitMQ version: 3.8.2
Node name: rabbit@thimonnier-desktop
Erlang configuration: Erlang/OTP 22 [erts-10.6.4] [source] [64-bit] [smp:12:12] [ds:12:12:10] [async-threads:192]
Erlang processes: 444 used, 1048576 limit
Scheduler run queue: 1
Cluster heartbeat timeout (net_ticktime): 60'
AMQP-CPP 4 https://github.com/CopernicaMarketingSoftware/AMQP-CPP

--> To learn and create these codes i followed instructions on this repo https://github.com/yuanhui360/CPP-Programming-on-Linux/tree/main/YH-109 ,  the codes are similar but it's a new version for the AMQPCPP 4 library.
Hopefully i have explained well what i did and some of you can help me.
Here are the codes respectively for my_publish and my_consume :

```
/**
 *  Method that is called by the AMQP library when the login attempt
 *  succeeded. After this method has been called, the connection is ready
 *  to use.
 *  @param  connection      The connection that can now be used
 */
virtual void onReady(AMQP::Connection *connection)
{
    // @todo
    //  add your own implementation, for example by creating a channel
    //  instance, and start publishing or consuming
}

/**
 *  Method that is called by the AMQP library when a fatal error occurs
 *  on the connection, for example because data received from RabbitMQ
 *  could not be recognized.
 *  @param  connection      The connection on which the error occurred
 *  @param  message         A human readable error message
 */
virtual void onError(AMQP::Connection *connection, const char *message)
{
    // @todo
    //  add your own implementation, for example by reporting the error
    //  to the user of your program, log the error, and destruct the
    //  connection object because it is no longer in a usable state
}

/**
 *  Method that is called when the connection was closed. This is the
 *  counter part of a call to Connection::close() and it confirms that the
 *  AMQP connection was correctly closed.
 *
 *  @param  connection      The connection that was closed and that is now unusable
 */
virtual void onClosed(AMQP::Connection *connection) 
{
    // @todo
    //  add your own implementation, for example by closing down the
    //  underlying TCP connection too
}
```

};

int main (int argc, char** argv) {

```
#include <amqpcpp.h>

//  amqp://[$USERNAME[:$PASSWORD]\@]$HOST[:$PORT]/[$VHOST]
//  AMQP amqp("test:test@192.168.0.106:5672/my_vhost");     // all connect string

using namespace std;

// You'll need to extend the ConnectionHandler class and make your own, like this
class MyConnectionHandler : public AMQP::ConnectionHandler
{
    /**
     *  Method that is called by the AMQP library every time it has data
     *  available that should be sent to RabbitMQ.
     *  @param  connection  pointer to the main connection object
     *  @param  data        memory buffer with the data that should be sent to RabbitMQ
     *  @param  size        size of the buffer
     */
    virtual void onData(AMQP::Connection *connection, const char *data, size_t size)
    {
        // @todo
        //  Add your own implementation, for example by doing a call to the
        //  send() system call. But be aware that the send() call may not
        //  send all data at once, so you also need to take care of buffering
        //  the bytes that could not immediately be sent, and try to send
        //  them again when the socket becomes writable again
        // AMQP::Channel channel(connection);
        // // Define the queue you want to consume from
        // const std::string queueName = "tcpp_image_message";
        // // Declare the queue
        // channel.declareQueue(queueName);
        // // Set up the message callback
        // channel.consume(queueName).onReceived([&channel](const AMQP::Message &message, uint64_t deliveryTag, bool redelivered) {
        //     // Handle the received message
        //     std::string data = message.body();
        //     std::cout << "Received message: " << data << std::endl;
        //     // Acknowledge the message to remove it from the queue
        //     channel.ack(deliveryTag);
        // });
    }

    /**
     *  Method that is called by the AMQP library when the login attempt
     *  succeeded. After this method has been called, the connection is ready
     *  to use.
     *  @param  connection      The connection that can now be used
     */
    virtual void onReady(AMQP::Connection *connection)
    {
        // @todo
        //  add your own implementation, for example by creating a channel
        //  instance, and start publishing or consuming
    }

    /**
     *  Method that is called by the AMQP library when a fatal error occurs
     *  on the connection, for example because data received from RabbitMQ
     *  could not be recognized.
     *  @param  connection      The connection on which the error occurred
     *  @param  message         A human readable error message
     */
    virtual void onError(AMQP::Connection *connection, const char *message)
    {
        // @todo
        //  add your own implementation, for example by reporting the error
        //  to the user of your program, log the error, and destruct the
        //  connection object because it is no longer in a usable state
    }

    /**
     *  Method that is called when the connection was closed. This is the
     *  counter part of a call to Connection::close() and it confirms that the
     *  AMQP connection was correctly closed.
     *
     *  @param  connection      The connection that was closed and that is now unusable
     */
    virtual void onClosed(AMQP::Connection *connection) 
    {
        // @todo
        //  add your own implementation, for example by closing down the
        //  underlying TCP connection too
    }


};

int main (int argc, char** argv) {
    std::string msg_body;

    if (argc != 3)
    {
        std::cout << "Usage: my_publish <host:port> <exchange> <queue>" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    
    
    char const* ex_name = argv[1];
    char const* queue_name = argv[2];
    const AMQP::Login login;
    
    try {
    
        MyConnectionHandler myHandler;
        AMQP::Connection connection(&myHandler, AMQP::Login("test", "test"), "/my_vhost");
        AMQP::Channel channel(&connection);
        channel.declareExchange(ex_name, AMQP::fanout);
        // create a custom callback
        auto callback = [](const std::string &name, int msgcount, int consumercount) {
    
            // @todo add your own implementation
    
        };
        
        channel.declareQueue(queue_name).onSuccess(std::move(callback));
        channel.bindQueue(ex_name, queue_name, "");
        // start a transaction
        channel.startTransaction();
        // Create a lambda function to publish a message
        auto publishMessage = [&channel, ex_name](const std::string& message) {  // Capture ex_name
        AMQP::Envelope env(message.c_str(), message.length());
        channel.publish(ex_name,"key", env);
        };
        // commit the transactions, and set up callbacks that are called when
        // the transaction was successful or not
        channel.commitTransaction()
            .onSuccess([]() {
                // all messages were successfully published
            })
            .onError([](const char *message) {
                // none of the messages were published
                // now we have to do it all over again
            });
    
        // Enter a loop to continuously wait for user input and publish messages
        while (true) {
            std::string userMessage;
            std::cout << "Enter a message to publish (or type 'exit' to quit): ";
            std::getline(std::cin, userMessage);
    
            if (userMessage == "exit") {
                break; // Exit the loop if the user enters 'exit'
            }
    
            // Publish the user's message
            publishMessage(userMessage);
            std::cout << "Execution Troubleshooting:";
        }
    
    } catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        // Handle the exception appropriately
    }
    return 0;
}

#include <amqpcpp.h>

//  amqp://[$USERNAME[:$PASSWORD]\@]$HOST[:$PORT]/[$VHOST]
//  AMQP amqp("test:test@192.168.0.106:5672/my_vhost");     // all connect string

using namespace std;

// You'll need to extend the ConnectionHandler class and make your own, like this
class MyConnectionHandler : public AMQP::ConnectionHandler
{
    /**
     *  Method that is called by the AMQP library every time it has data
     *  available that should be sent to RabbitMQ.
     *  @param  connection  pointer to the main connection object
     *  @param  data        memory buffer with the data that should be sent to RabbitMQ
     *  @param  size        size of the buffer
     */
    virtual void onData(AMQP::Connection *connection, const char *data, size_t size)
    {
        // @todo
        //  Add your own implementation, for example by doing a call to the
        //  send() system call. But be aware that the send() call may not
        //  send all data at once, so you also need to take care of buffering
        //  the bytes that could not immediately be sent, and try to send
        //  them again when the socket becomes writable again
        // AMQP::Channel channel(connection);
        // // Define the queue you want to consume from
        // const std::string queueName = "tcpp_image_message";
        // // Declare the queue
        // channel.declareQueue(queueName);
        // // Set up the message callback
        // channel.consume(queueName).onReceived([&channel](const AMQP::Message &message, uint64_t deliveryTag, bool redelivered) {
        //     // Handle the received message
        //     std::string data = message.body();
        //     std::cout << "Received message: " << data << std::endl;
        //     // Acknowledge the message to remove it from the queue
        //     channel.ack(deliveryTag);
        // });
    }
/**
 *  Method that is called by the AMQP library when the login attempt
 *  succeeded. After this method has been called, the connection is ready
 *  to use.
 *  @param  connection      The connection that can now be used
 */
virtual void onReady(AMQP::Connection *connection)
{
    // @todo
    //  add your own implementation, for example by creating a channel
    //  instance, and start publishing or consuming
}

/**
 *  Method that is called by the AMQP library when a fatal error occurs
 *  on the connection, for example because data received from RabbitMQ
 *  could not be recognized.
 *  @param  connection      The connection on which the error occurred
 *  @param  message         A human readable error message
 */
virtual void onError(AMQP::Connection *connection, const char *message)
{
    // @todo
    //  add your own implementation, for example by reporting the error
    //  to the user of your program, log the error, and destruct the
    //  connection object because it is no longer in a usable state
}

/**
 *  Method that is called when the connection was closed. This is the
 *  counter part of a call to Connection::close() and it confirms that the
 *  AMQP connection was correctly closed.
 *
 *  @param  connection      The connection that was closed and that is now unusable
 */
virtual void onClosed(AMQP::Connection *connection) 
{
    // @todo
    //  add your own implementation, for example by closing down the
    //  underlying TCP connection too
}

int main (int argc, char** argv) {
    
    std::string msg_body;
    
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        std::cout << "Usage: my_consume <host:port> <queue>" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    
    
    char const* queue_name = argv[1];
    
    try {
    
        MyConnectionHandler myHandler;
        AMQP::Connection connection(&myHandler, AMQP::Login("test", "test"), "/my_vhost");
        AMQP::Channel channel(&connection);
        channel.declareQueue(queue_name);
        // callback function that is called when the consume operation starts
        auto startCb = [](const std::string &consumertag) {
    
            std::cout << "consume operation started" << std::endl;
        };
    
        // callback function that is called when the consume operation failed
        auto errorCb = [](const char *message) {
    
            std::cout << "consume operation failed" << std::endl;
        };
    
        // callback operation when a message was received
        auto messageCb = [&channel](const AMQP::Message &message, uint64_t deliveryTag, bool redelivered) {
    
            std::cout << "message received" << std::endl;
    
            // acknowledge the message
            channel.ack(deliveryTag);
        };
    
        // callback that is called when the consumer is cancelled by RabbitMQ (this only happens in
        // rare situations, for example when someone removes the queue that you are consuming from)
        auto cancelledCb = [](const std::string &consumertag) {
    
            std::cout << "consume operation cancelled by the RabbitMQ server" << std::endl;
        };
    
        // start consuming from the queue, and install the callbacks
        channel.consume(queue_name)
            .onReceived(messageCb)
            .onSuccess(startCb)
            .onCancelled(cancelledCb)
            .onError(errorCb);
    
    
    
        // Other application logic, error handling, and cleanup
    
    } catch (const std::exception &e) {
        std::cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        // Handle the exception appropriately
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Terminal :

$ make clean
rm -f *.o my_consume  my_get  my_publish

$ make my_publish my_consume

g++ -c -Wall -g -std=c++17 -I/usr/include my_publish.cpp -o my_publish.o

g++ -lssh -pthread -Wl,--no-as-needed -ldl -L /usr/lib -L /usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu -lrabbitmq -lamqpcpp my_publish.o -o my_publish
g

++ -c -Wall -g -std=c++17 -I/usr/include my_consume.cpp -o my_consume.o

g++ -lssh -pthread -Wl,--no-as-needed -ldl -L /usr/lib -L /usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu -lrabbitmq -lamqpcpp my_consume.o -o my_consume

$ ./my_publish my_exchange my_queue
Enter a message to publish (or type 'exit' to quit): Hi RabbitMQ message, my name is moumout
Execution Troubleshooting:Enter a message to publish (or type 'exit' to quit): exit

$ ./my_consume my_queue   #### Expected "message received", printed nothing

$